# Store into two tables in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, module, database

I have a custom module, which uses two tables to store data in database. table 1 and table 2 are conntected by storing the id of table1 in one of the field of table2. In order to store datas to table2, I am using protected function **_aftersave()**. Here is my aftersave method

```
// this function will get executed before the model is saved but after save function has been called
    protected function _afterSave( Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object )
    {
        // do some model loads and checks here so that you will update existing data and not duplicate rows on editAction saves...\
        $frontendModel = Mage::getModel( 'news/newsfrontend' );
       //loading item in table2 with current table1 id
        $frontendCollection=$frontendModel->getCollection()
              ->addFieldToFilter('news_parent_id', array('eq' => $object->getId()))
              ->getLastItem();
        if(!$frontendCollection->isEmpty()) //check whether any item exist or not
        {
          //saving news data to existing item
            $frontendCollection->setData("news_parent_id",$object->getId())->save();
            $frontendCollection->setData($object->getData())->save();
        }
        else
        {
            //storing new datas to new item
            $frontendModel->setData("news_parent_id",$object->getId())->save();
            $frontendModel->setData($object->getData())->save();
        }


      return parent::_beforeSave( $object );
    }
```

The problem that I am facing now are

1) `news_parent_id` is not setting after save action. Rest datas are saving
     in table2

2)Is this the correct approach to my problem?

3)How can I set `news_parent_id` correctly?

4)Is there any easy way for achieving this?

5)if I am using `_beforesave()`, how can I get the table1 id in order to set the `news_parent_id` through it?

Please enlighten me with your ideas and suggestions. Awaiting for your response. Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/436/how-to-save-form-data-to-multiple-tables-in-database

Comment: @EvgeniIvanov : actaually this link gave me idea of `beforesave`  and  `aftersave` methods.lol. I want to know how can we use _beforesave_ for this purpose. I have done it by _aftersave_ method :)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I need to answer my own question. In fact, It is not a difficult thing. Because I am close to the real answer. Here is my 'working' `_aftersave()` method. Take a look

```
protected function _afterSave( Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object )
    {
        // do some model loads and checks here so that you will update existing data and not duplicate rows on editAction saves...\
        $frontendModel = Mage::getModel( 'news/newsfrontend' );
        $frontendCollection=$frontendModel->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('news_parent_id', array('eq' => $object->getId()))->getFirstItem();
        if(!$frontendCollection->isEmpty())
        {
            $frontendCollection->addData($object->getData())->save();
        }
        else
        {
            $frontendModel->setData($object->getData());
            $frontendModel->setData("news_parent_id",$object->getId());
            $frontendModel->save();
        }


      return parent::_afterSave( $object );
    }
```

*$object* holds my posted datas actually reference to the base table I think. I am loading my table2 using _getModel_method. If condition checks whether there is already an entry in table2 correspond for the item in table1. If yes, it updates that field otherwise it will set a new item in table2. Thats it.

Still I dont know how to use *beforesave* for this purpose. If I got a hint on this, I will definitely make an edit on this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this piece of code:

```
protected function _afterSave( Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object )
    {
        // do some model loads and checks here so that you will update existing data and not duplicate rows on editAction saves...\
        $frontendModel = Mage::getModel( 'news/newsfrontend' )->load($object->getId(), 'news_parent_id');

        $data = $object->getData();
        unset($data['id']);

        if($frontendModel->getId())
        {
            // use addData() instead of setData() to retain news_parent_id field
            $frontendModel->addData($object->getData())
                ->save();
        }
        else
        {
            $frontendModel->unsetData();
            $frontendModel->setData($object->getData())
                ->save();
        }

      return parent::_afterSave( $object );
    }
```